# Post-apocalyptic book set on the Snake River

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic

I read a book in middle school set on the Snake River, it was post-apocalyptic/post-cataclysm.

The primary character escapes on a river barge, avoids danger, I think a cult and saves a young girl in the process.

Comment: Is the "Snake River" a real world place? A setting for the story? A metaphor?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_River

Comment: A book with similar happenings is River Rats by Caroline Stevermer. A group of kids travel on the Mississippi in a steam ship (paddlewheel). They rescue a man and then have to evade the cult members who are trying to capture the man.